# So... do we have to start polyfilling for chrome's calendar now?

Tags: html, google-chrome, date, datepicker, modernizr

Looks like Chrome may finally have a release of their `<input type="date" />` control. How would one go about polyfilling around this with modernizr?

Comment: The fact that it is now implemented means that you don't have to polyfill it any more. You can let the browser's native date picker do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information comes from [an HTML5Rocks post](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome).

If you'd like to apply jQuery Datepicker or another JS calendar library on all platforms, use input[type=text] instead of input[type=date]. This is the best way to ensure a consistent UI since different browsers which have support for input[type=date] do it in different ways.

You can use Modernizr or your own check to see if the browser supports this input type and then either let it use native or use a JS library.

```
var isDateInputSupported = function(){
  var elem = document.createElement('input');
  elem.setAttribute('type','date');
  elem.value = 'foo';
  return (elem.type == 'date' && elem.value != 'foo');
}

if (!isDateInputSupported())  { // or.. !Modernizr.inputtypes.date
  $('input[type="date"]').datepicker();
}
```